# Where can I find documentation on what "\char" does?

Tags: tex-core

I've seen samples of TeX using

```
\char`\\
```

to produce a literal backslash. Where can I find documentation on what the `\char` command does? Is it a generic construct to safely produce reserved literals?

Comment: In the TeXBook by D. E. Knuth perhaps? It's a primitive, anyway

Comment: `\char number` outputs the letter/symbol according to the encoding: `\char 65` would print 'A' (Ascii code), `\def\foo{66}` and `\char\foo` would print 'B' then

Comment: note that if you are using latex the supported syntax is `\symbol{\`\\}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've tried using symbol (MWE at  https://gist.github.com/retorquere/540afe23e704b0bd301f), but for some reason, \symbol{`\\} renders to double-quotes.

Comment: @retorquere yes so will `\char` if you use OT1 encoding.

Comment: `\char\`\\ ` does not typeset a `\ ` it typesets whatever is in slot 92 in the current font which is a double quote in classic TeX (OT1) encoding.

Comment: There are three independent problems. First: knowledge about `\char number` ... it prints the character from the slot `number` of the current font. That is whole documentation. Second: `number` can be written in more TeX primitive formats. One of them is `backtie some` where `some` is `backslash character` or directly `character` (like `\b` or `b`). The `backslash character` format is more compact when you are using special characters. Third: you need to have the right character in the given slot of actual font. This is not always true in classical Knuth's fonts as mentioned by David.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I cite the [TeX By Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) book by Viktor Eijkhout.

Here is a an excerpt

[image]

`\char` is basically just for conversion of numbers to a character representation, using the underlying encoding.

`'82` uses octal numbers, `"82` means hexadecimal numbers.

The last sentence in this excerpt says all: **`typeset character number so-and-so`**

Comment: [`texdoc texbytopic`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) to get a PDF of the book.

Comment: @TorbjørnT: I've done that, but perhaps not everybody has the full TL installed, that's why I provided the link

Comment: I started writing my comment (which I also edited to include a link) before you added the link.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Coincidence ;-) I always edit my answers in the first minutes, so it's never the final version ;-)

Comment: I did not know about "texdoc texbytopic", so super thanks for that!

Comment: @retorquere: I suggest to buy the latest printed copy

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, good one, just did.

Comment: If I understand texbytopic correctly, the resulting output is directly dependent on the font in use -- it is not safe to assume that \char92 will output a backslash under all circumstances, correct?

Comment: @retorquere That's no different from if you type in the character yourself. There's no certainly that the font used for output will look like the input: probably the most obvious example of this is using a pifont.

Comment: +1 I'd just emphasize more the word *typeset*: it's a rather common misunderstanding that `\char` produces the character for later usage in a token list, but this is false. With XeTeX and LuaTeX one can use `\Uchar` for that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it says `Sorry, no documentation found for texbytopic.`. Maybe do you know how to compile it? I've cloned the repo of the book, but README says nothing about compilation, and blind attempts of `latex TexByTopic.tex` and `texpdf TexByTopic.tex` end up with errors.

Comment: @Hi-Angel You can get a PDF from https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic, or buy a printed version from http://www.lulu.com/shop/victor-eijkhout/tex-by-topic/paperback/product-23132527.html

Comment: @Hi-Angel Or you can click the link in my comment.

Comment: FTR after I fugured out how to compile it, [I've elaborated it in the README](https://bitbucket.org/VictorEijkhout/tex-by-topic/pull-requests/1/readme-explain-building-process-on/diff#comment-47040026); I suspect pull request will hang there for years though, so I'm linking it here in case it helps somebody.